# Why a convex cone cannot have more than one extreme point?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I define an extreme point as a point $x$ (in some set $S$) which cannot be defined as a convex combination of two distinct points $x_1$ and $x_2$ (both in $S$). I.e., if $x=\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2$ for distinct $x_1$ and $x_2$, and $\lambda\in [0,1]$, then $x=x_1=x_2$.

I'm not able to extend this and show why a convex cone cannot have more than one extreme point. Here, a convex cone is a (i) cone $C$, i.e. for all $x\in C$, $\lambda x\in C$ for all $\lambda\geq 0$, which (ii) is convex.

Can someone give me more geometric intuition behind this concept?

This was asked in my exam, and I was not convinced with my prof's explanation.

Thank you

Comment: What's the definition of a convex cone?

Comment: @zhw : A subset C of a vector space V is a convex cone if αx + βy belongs to C, for any positive scalars α, β, and any x, y in C. - wikipedia

Answer (score 5):

Let $C$ be a cone and let $x \in C$.  Suppose $x \neq 0$.

Then $x$ is a convex combination of the points $y_1 = \frac12 x$ and $y_2 = \frac32 x$, both of which belong to $C$.

Explicitly, $x = \frac12 y_1 + \frac12 y_2$.

This shows that $x$ is not an extreme point of $C$.  It follows that the origin is the only possible extreme point of $C$.

(We don't need the assumption that $C$ is convex.)

Answer (score 1):

**Geometric Intuition of Extreme Point:** According to your definition of extreme point, geometric intuition of an extreme point in a convex are all corners. For example, in a triangle you extreme points are just the corners. However, in some other convex sets like disk (filled circle), extreme points are all the points on the border.

**Geometric Intuition of Convex Cone:**
Look at this link for a geometric description of a convex cone.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone

**Observation:** According to these the two statements above, you can see that only the origin can be an extreme point for a convex cone. So, if the convex cone includes the origin it has only one extreme point, and if it doesn't it has no extreme points.